# How we can find the total no of website visitors in Php?

Tags: php, yii2

I created a website before one year ago and now i want to add a functionality to view the total number of visitor from launching the site live till now.
The website is in Yii2 framework.
If there is any solution please answer me.

Thanks.

Comment: No you can't get past data.. all you can get data from now onwards

Comment: You should really ask this one year ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question. You can try to parse the Access-Log of your webserver and use tools like [AWStats](http://www.awstats.org/%20AWStats) for that.